# In R studio I receive an error for a post hoc test TukeyHSD for a two-way ANOVA with an interaction

Tags: r, anova, two-way, posthoc

This is everything I entered and the output.

```
two.way <- aov(Facefactor ~ Teamsport + College + College:Teamsport, data = Male_Data_R_Face_Factor)
summary(two.way)
                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Teamsport           1   0.29  0.2860   0.343  0.559
College             1   0.05  0.0541   0.065  0.799
Teamsport:College   1   1.05  1.0538   1.262  0.263
Residuals         206 171.99  0.8349               
TukeyHSD(two.way)
```

> Error in TukeyHSD.aov(two.way) : no factors in the fitted model
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
> non-factors ignored: Teamsport
> 2: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
> non-factors ignored: College
> 3: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
> non-factors ignored: Teamsport, College

Comment: Please provide a small example of your data, I believe that your IVs are not classified as factors, but as numeric. Check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that your factors are factors:
put this code before aov.

```
Male_Data_R_Face_Factor <- within(Male_Data_R_Face_Factor, {
  Teamsport  <- factor(Teamsport)
  College <- factor(College)
})
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It looks like that (making sure factors are factors) worked as I did not get an error message.